# How to order the records from different records with matching data in two differents columns as continous rows in output

Tags: sql, oracle11g, hive, tableau-api

Need help with Oracle query which will provide the output in below the format.

Sample table

```
c1 c2 c3 c4
-- -- -- -- 
 A  1 A1
 B  2 B1 C1
 D  6 E2 A1
 A  2    A1
 C  3 C1
 D  4 D1 E1
```

I want to join same table where data in 3rd Column matches the data in 4th and expecting the data to be sorted as subsequent records  as below

```
c1 c2 c3 c4
-- -- -- -- 
 A  1 A1
 A  2    A1
 D  6 E2 A1
 B  2 B1 C1
 C  3 C1
```

Comment: Mani - you need records for which data in 3rd column matches with fourth column, but in output you have records (3 and 4) which are not there in fourth column, can provide the right data set

Comment: In 1st row  3rd column in table matches with 4th column of 3rd row and 5th row 3rd column matches with 4th column of 2nd hence its there in output

Comment: then how come you have 3rd row and 4th row in expected output, 3rd row col3 value - E2 is not there in 4th col and 4th row col3 value - B1 is not there in 4th column

Comment: In output since 1st row 3rd column - A1 matches with 4th row 4th column - A1 and 5th row 3rd column -C1 matches with 4th row 4th colum - C1

Answer (score 0):

That's not a grouping, it's a sorting that you need:

```
select *
from your_table
order by coalesce(col1,'ZZZ') desc, 
                  col2 desc --coalesce will use 'ZZZ' to order if column is null
```

Comment: it does not work as it would first order the columns using the Col1 and then records with Col2 as in some scenrios Col1 can be null or have some data which would put record some other position

Comment: @MANI Add theose 'scenarios' to sample data; we can't imagine those for you

Comment: thanks for the prompt response. I have add that scenerio as well. let me know if it helps